# First In, First Out (FIFO) Inventory

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, fifo

Let's say I have the following two records;

```
 tran_id     item_id     qty_in     qty_out     price
    1            1           15           0      1.50
    2            1           15           0      1.60
```

Now, when I want to consume 20 units of item_id 1, I want to consume 15 of rated 1.50 and 5 of rated 1.60 on a FIFO.

Can somebody give me an idea as to how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement could look something like this

```
select * from tablename where item_id = 1 order by tran_id asc
```

That should give you your records with the first items at the top and so on.  Then in your java code you can adjust the quantities accordingly.

Comment: I can get the same result without the order by clause.

Comment: And that doesn't give you the results you want?  Other than either using a sort in your code or in the SQL I don't see any other way to do it.

Comment: What if I had consumed 5 of the first batch before trying to use 10+10.  How do I know how many of the first batch to take and how many of the next?

Comment: I guess I'm not following.  If you consume 5 of the first batch then the next batch of 20 would take 10 from the first record and 10 from the second record. You would be left with 0 in the first batch and 5 in the second.